# Unable to get CGRect.null and CGPoint in Package after upgrading to Xcode 14.1

Tags: xcode, macos, core-graphics, swift-package-manager, foundation

I have a MacOS package dependency which defines some class: [FontPens](https://github.com/dcsch/fontpens)

```
  import Foundation
  ...
  public class BoundsPen: Pen {

        var bounds = CGRect.null
        private var currentPoint = CGPoint.zero
        ....
```

After upgrading Xcode to 14.1 both lines throws errors `Type 'CGRect' has no member 'null'` and `Type 'CGPoint' has no member 'zero'`.

Calling `CGPoint.zero` and `CGRect.null` from an app is OK if `Foundation` is imported.

Is it a way to solve this problem without changing package source?

Comment: “Calling `CGPoint.zero` and `CGRect.null` from an app is OK if `Foundation` is imported.” ... I believe that `.zero` is available from `Foundation`, but the `.null` (and lots of other useful methods) are only with `CoreGraphics`.

Answer (score 0):

`CGPoint` and `CGRect` are both defined in `CoreGraphics`, not `Foundation`.  That is the import that this file should be doing. It's possible that `CoreGraphics` was being implicitly imported before, but isn't now, but that's hard to say without seeing the rest of the code.

Comment: Technically, `CGRect` and `CGPoint` appear to be defined in `Foundation`, and it is just the useful extension (which includes, amongst other things, `.null`) that is defined in `CoreGraphics`.

Comment: @jrturton: I made a test on local file: I imported only `Foundation` and it was OK. Before upgrading to 14.1 it was OK too.